# Pig Latin in Java

Tags: java, strings, pig-latin

I've done my second application in Java now. I want to know if:

- This code is efficient
- This code can be written in a shorter and faster way
- Any flaws
- Any misuse or better use of concepts

Main Class:

```
package Excercises;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PigLatin pigLatin = new PigLatin();

        pigLatin.initializeText();
        pigLatin.getWord();
        pigLatin.convertWordToStringArray();
        pigLatin.convertArrayToList();
        pigLatin.moveFirstLetterToLast();
        pigLatin.mergeList();

        System.out.println(pigLatin.returnNewWord());
    }
}
```

PigLatin class:

```
package Excercises;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PigLatin {
    private String word;
    private String newWord;
    private String[] Array;
    private List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    public void initializeText() {
        System.out.print("Welcome to the Pig Latin Game! Please enter a word: ");
    }

    public void getWord() {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        this.word = scan.next();
    }

    public void convertWordToStringArray() {
        this.Array = word.split("");
    }

    public void convertArrayToList() {
        for(String s : this.Array) {
            this.list.add(s);
        }
    }

    public void moveFirstLetterToLast() {
        this.list.add("-");
        this.list.add(this.Array[0]);
        this.list.remove(0);
        this.list.add("ay");
    }

    public void mergeList() {
        for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            this.newWord = this.newWord + list.get(i);
        }
        this.newWord = this.newWord.replaceAll("null", "");
    }

    public String returnNewWord() {
        return this.newWord;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not really related to code review, but [the rules for Pig Latin are not that simple.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pig_Latin#Rules) You are supposed to move *all* of the beginning letters *up to the first vowel*. If the word begins with a vowel, you just add "way" to the end.

Comment: Where i found this idea it said what ai did

Comment: *what I did just now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Input and general structure**

Right now, the only possible way to use your class is via the command line. This makes testing really hard. I would change your `getWord` function to a simple `setWord(String word)` setter, and read the word in outside the class (somewhere in `Main`).

And in general, your `PigLatin` class should only transform words to piglatin, not also print and read. I would move `initializeText` to `Main` as well.

And your public interface for `PigLatin` is quite hard to manage. I would make all those methods private, and then either create a `toPigLatin` method, or just call them in `returnNewWord`.

I also think that you could merge some of the methods. At least `convertWordToStringArray` and `convertArrayToList` could well be in one method (`wordToCharList` or something).

Your naming is sometimes not very precise. For example, `moveFirstLetterToLast` also adds `ay`, which is unexpected.

> This code is efficient

Probably not. You are iterating over the whole string twice, which is not necessary.

> This code can be written in a shorter and faster way

Sure, there are lots of ways. For example:

```
   String s;
   char firstChar = s.charAt(0);
   String piglatin = s.substring(1) + "-" + firstChar + "ay";
```

It's probably not *the* fastest way, but it should be faster than your approach.

Comment: wow.... thats only a few lines. I'm such a noob. -.-

Comment: +1 This covers a lot of important points. I think it's worth repeating for emphasis that a class should not just expose every stage of its process as a public method and have the caller call each of them in turn. Because now two classes need to know how the process works: the actual class, and its caller.

Answer (score 10):

It's much cleaner to iterate through a `List` using a foreach loop:

```
for (String s : list) {
    this.newWord = this.newWord + s;
}
```

And you can use the `+=` operator to append onto the end of a `String`:

```
for (String s : list) {
    this.newWord += s;
}
```

But it's more efficient to use the `StringBuilder` class when performing multiple string concatenations.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (String s : list) {
    sb.append(s);
}
this.newWord = sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 6):

> Any flaws?

Yep, you don't seem to generate a correct output:

```
STDIN
>>> Generic
STDOUT
>>> Welcome to the Pig Latin Game! Please enter a word:
... Generic-ay
```

> I want to know if this code can be written in a shorter and faster way

I suppose you can do this instead, here you go:

```
package Excercises;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Welcome to the Pig Latin Game! Please enter a sentence: ");
        System.out.println(java.util.Scanner(System.in).nextLine().replaceAll("(\\w)(\\w+)", "$2-$1ay"));
    }
}
```

With regex replacement, you can handle the entire line without constructing a `List`, an array, and constantly creating new `String` objects. You can replace the entire line with the code too:

```
STDIN
>>> Generic sentences are so funny.
STDOUT
>>> Welcome to the Pig Latin Game! Please enter a word:
... eneric-Gay entences-say re-aay o-say unny-fay.
```

Comment: I think that you copied the code wrong. For me it works fine, eg `code` -> `ode-cay`

Comment: @tim Is that so? I ran it on ideone: http://ideone.com/0XGblY

Comment: I ran it locally and it works fine. I'm using Java 8 (but I don't think that that would make a difference).

Comment: It works fine for me. I am using Java 8.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think anyone here's code handles vowels at all, I believe a Pig Latin creator should actually move the first consonants to the end (which may be nothing) and add -ay

Pseudocode (operating on a single word):

```
list-of-consonants = []
index = 0
while(current-letter.is-consonant) do
    list-of-consonants.add(current-letter)
    index++
end
output-string =
    original-word.substring-starting-at(index) concat-with
    "-" concat-with
    list-of-consonants concat-with
    "ay"
```

On a more practical level, checking if something is a consonant will probably be done with a simple array check. I think Java's substring method has an overload that just takes an int, which will do a substring starting at an index and ending at the end of the string.

This means that "are" gets changed to "are-ay" instead of "re-aay" and "Philadelphia" gets changed to "iladelphia-Phay" (maybe you should handle capitals somehow but this probably doesn't matter too much)

Comment: But here it is code review.